# How to call a static method on a base class from a generic class<T>?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call a static method in a base class from a generic subclass. See simplified playground code below.

Calling the non-static 'dump' function works.
The similar static call fails. Various attempts to typecast the array also fail.

In the full production code, "ClassA" is in a 3rd-party module and can't be changed. It can be further subclassed and extended.

Does Swift offer some magical typecast to have ClassT call ClassA.dump() directly?

```
class ClassT<T> {

    var dict=[String:T]()

    func add(key:String, obj:T) {
        dict[key]=obj
        let arr=Array(dict.values)
        dump(arr) // works -> but not as expected, see comment below !!!
        ClassA.dump(arr) // error: cannot convert value of type 'Array<T>' to expected argument type '[ClassA]'
        ClassA.dump(arr as! [ClassA]) // error: cannot convert value of type 'Array<T>' to type '[ClassA]' in coercion
        ClassA.dump(arr as! [AnyObject]) // error: 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'T'
        ClassA.dump(arr as! [Any]) // error: 'Any' is not a subtype of 'T'
    }

}

class ClassA {

    func dump(arr:[ClassA]) {
        ClassA.dump(arr)
    }

    static func dump(arr:[ClassA]) {
        print(arr)
    }
}

class ClassB:ClassA {

    static let o=ClassT<ClassA>()

    func test() {
        ClassB.o.add("Elem1", obj:self)
    }
}
```

Comment: alt-click on your `dump(arr)`, it's not the function you're expecting to call – it's the global `dump` function.

Comment: @originaluser2, thanks! Totally missed that. Renamed the function and now the 'workaround' also fails. Answer below however solves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a constraint to specify that `T` derives from `ClassA`.

```
class ClassT<T: ClassA> {

    var dict = [String : T]()

    func add(key: String, obj: T) {
        dict[key] = obj
        let arr = Array(dict.values) //probably unecessary
        dump(arr) // works
        ClassA.dump(arr)
    }
    //...
```

Without it, the compiler has no way to enforce that all conforming types `T` will be castable to `ClassA`.